# WF4 Passing parameters to my activity using WorkflowInvoker.Invoke Method

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

In [WorkflowInvoker.Invoke Method (Activity, IDictionary)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988928.aspx)
The second parameter takes the arguments for the activity (first parameter). Does it just takes "InArguments" or is there a way can I set any public property of the activity?  Specificly if my custom activity has properties that require activities as arguments(I.E child activity in an activity). Msdn docs and source not exactly all that clear to me. Thx!

Comment: I don't get your question clearly. Do you mean to ask how you can set a public property of the activity parameter?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, Yes I can. my issue was with my parent activity. I added an unnecessary level of complexity to the whole damn thing. I can get into details if anyone would like. If not I guess I just SO to answer my own question again lol...

Comment: I'm not the one who down-voted you, but I can make a guess: Your "answer" isn't a good answer, it's just "yes I can". How about you explain why or how you can? That would probably make your answer more appealing to people.

Comment: I said I would gladly go into detail if anyone cared to know. Instead of down voting they could just say they wanted to know more. And in general people comment when down voting as a matter of etiquette.

Comment: I agree, I think it is terribly bad form to down-vote someone and not tell them why.